# Порядок выполнения операторов Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть такое условие:

```
WHERE (QuestionName LIKE '%золото%' OR QuestionText LIKE '%золото%' AND qc.question_categoryIdCategory=5)
```

В базе данных нет значения: **qc.question_categoryIdCategory=5**
Но запрос все равно выполняется по LIKE
Как я понимаю, нужно расставить скобки (OR) AND...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приоритет выполнения операторов такой: NOT, AND, OR. 
[Здесь](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_predicates_1/page2.html) почитайте.